# Need a Lookup Function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, lookup

[image: Chart 1]

[image: Chart 2]

I'm looking for a lookup function for cell K5. I want a percentage number based on the relationship between "Planned #Rep", or B5:B15, and "Actual #Rep", or E5:E15, using the bottom chart as a reference.

For example, if I planned to do 3 reps but only managed to do 2 reps, or 1 less rep, then the function in K5 would retrieve 4% (F39).

In the example above I planned to do 1 rep (B8), but was able to get none (E8), thus 1 less rep, which would retrieve 5% (C39).

What function can I use to make this happen?

Comment: `index` and `match` would probably be best.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

in K5

```
=INDEX($C$39:$N$41,B5-E5,MATCH(B5,$C$38:$N$38))
```

Copy/fill the formula down to K15.

Breakdown of formula:

1. Reference the lookup table

   =INDEX($C$39:$N$41,
2. Row is determined by calculating 'Reps Less'

   B5-E5,
3. Column is determined by referencing Reps Planned (B5) and returning the column number within the range $C$38:$N$38.

   MATCH(B5,$C$38:$N$38))

---

On second thought - you really don't need the Match portion of the formula. Instead of using a match formula for the column, you can take the # of Planned Reps as is. Like this (entered into cell 'K5'):

```
=INDEX($C$39:$N$41,B5-E5,B5)
```